Unable to match the results when converting the Excel Trend formula to SQL
We have a requirement to convert Excel Trend logic to SQL using Azure SQL Editor, but the SQL results do not match.
When I used the below logic getting null for Trend, also i have tried the multiple conditions(using slope & intercept,Linear_Regression) but results are not matched.
If anyone has an idea, please respond to this.
Data
[enter image description here]
(https://i.sstatic.net/xtepxhiI.png)
Quantiy_in_KG
76.1,11.4,3.6,1.1
Customer_Achieved_avg_price_in_kg
651.9,652.67,666.94,1050.18
Trend_to_sql
682.91,742.07,749.2,751.48
Example logic1:
WITH RegressionStats AS (
SELECT
CORR(quantity_in_kg, Customer_achieved_price) / VAR(quantity_in_kg) AS slope,
AVG(Customer_achieved_price) - slope \* AVG(quantity_in_kg) AS intercept
FROM
your_table_name
)

-- Calculate predicted values
SELECT
quantity_in_kg,
Customer_achieved_price,
slope \* quantity_in_kg + intercept AS predicted_price
FROM
your_table_name
CROSS JOIN RegressionStats;

Example Logic 2nd
Select
quantity_in_kg,
Customer_achieved_price,
(Slope \* quantity_in_kg + INTERCEPT) as Trend
From
(SELECT
quantity_in_kg,
Customer_achieved_price,
REGR_SLOPE(Customer_achieved_price,quantity_in_kg) OVER() AS SLOPE,
REGR_INTERCEPTCustomer_achieved_price,quantity_in_kg) OVER() AS INTERCEPT
From data
)

Expected Results
enter image description here
Expecting assistance from the Stack Community to move forward.

Trend_to_sql is your expected output?

I have used your data and created the trend in excel and in databricks sql, both results are matching.
Below is the excel trend results.

and in databricks using below code.
SELECT
regr_slope(Customer_Achieved_avg_price_in_kg,Quantity_in_KG) OVER () as slope,
regr_intercept(Customer_Achieved_avg_price_in_kg,Quantity_in_KG) OVER () as intercept,
Quantity_in_KG,
Customer_Achieved_avg_price_in_kg,
slope * Quantity_in_KG + intercept AS trend
FROM
your_table_name

Output:

Here, both the results are matching.
You are getting different results, because either you are not using the TREND function correctly or testing on different values of Quantity_in_KG, please check it properly.

Thanks for the response,let me try and get back to you.

When I attempted to run the above actual query, the results differed. I will upload an image for you to review, so please take a look and respond as soon as possible, @JayashankarGS.

When I attempted to run the above actual query, the results differed. I have uploaded upload an image for you to review, so please take a look and respond as soon as possible(I'm new to Stack Overflow and I'm struggling with my query as I'm not sure how to arrange it. I have no knowledge about the available options.) @JayashankarGS.

I applied the logic you recommended involving Slope and Intercept using REGR, but the results were not as anticipated. If you could, please modify my query as needed. When I executed my query, the expected Trend result was 682.91, but I received a Trend result of 512.7500, which does not align with the expected results. @JayashankarGS.

how you expecting 682.91, where you calculated? in excel Trend function?  both in sql and excel it is giving me 629.5.

the reason i am getting like this is because i used the samples you have given in the question. the slope and intercept vary according to the data you have.

Yes correct depends on data volume it might change but my query given 512 only but the expected is 682.please correct me where I'm doing wrong(above given the query).

How you calculated 682. Please add more details on it.

I tried the logic you suggested above, and the results are what I expected. Thank you for your help. @JayashankarGS
